# Display images in a TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I want to display images in a `TableView`. I can display one image in one cell, but I want to display four images instead of one image in every row like a photo library and when I select any image, it will open as a slide show as it happened in the photo library.

My images are stored in Document Directory. How can I do this?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tablView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //Adjust your imageview frame according to you
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 470.0, 80.0)];

    [imageView setImage:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using UITableView ... i think you should use UISCrollView instead of TableView

Comment: i think you should use image caching method

Comment: @VakulSaini that is possible in scroll view which i want????

Comment: @elppa i dnt have any idea about image caching method... can u help me

Comment: @VakulSaini wow gr8... can u help me how????

Comment: see this http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/image-caching-in-iphone-sdk/

Comment: @elppa  gud tutorial..... it will help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now I'm just explaining how to show an image like iPhone library. Use **UIScrollView** instead of **UITableView**. I think this will be better!

After getting all images in an array, try this code:

```
-(void)loadImagesOnScrollView
{
    myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 416.0)];
    myScrollView.delegate = self;
    myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 416.0);
    myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myScrollView];

    float horizontal = 8.0;
    float vertical = 8.0;

    for(int i=0; i<[imageArray count]; i++)
    {
        if((i%4) == 0 && i!=0)
        {
            horizontal = 8.0;
            vertical = vertical + 70.0 + 8.0;
        }

        buttonImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [buttonImage setFrame:CGRectMake(horizontal, vertical, 70.0, 70.0)];
        [buttonImage setTag:i];
        [buttonImage setImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonImage addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonImagePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [myScrollView addSubview:buttonImage];

        horizontal = horizontal + 70.0 + 8.0;
    }

    [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, vertical + 78.0)];
}
```

And you can handle each image like this

```
-(void)buttonImagePressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"you have pressed : %d button",[sender tag]);
}
```

(**Note: First of all, this is up to you and your logics so please make your logic strong. Nobody can write everything here. If you are a beginner then please do study for sometime "All The Very Best"**)

Comment: :-) .... dont get me in wrong way... but this is good for you :-) ....is above code working for you ?

Comment: remove all the codes what you wrote for UITableView..... after getting all images in arrayOfImages use this code ... it will work for sure

Comment: I removed all code for UITable View... and i also add this line at the end  [self.view addSubview:myScrollView];   it add scroll view but not displaying buttons....

Comment: no dont write this [self.view addSubview:myScrollView]; ....listen just declare -(void)loadImagesOnScrollView; in your .h file and then just paste above method in your .m file..... then call it this method just after where you got all the images in array ...[self loadImagesOnScrollView] like this ....

Comment: hey its working now... i just did few changes... i  add  [self.view addSubview:myScrollView]  in the end of this method (void)loadImagesOnScrollView... first i was mistaking that i called this method in viewdidload, but now i called this method where i got all images in array.....

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create and layout a new UIView and add your images to that. Then you can add that view to the cell's `contentView`, instead of the `UIImageView` (that only holds one image) that you are currently adding.

Comment: number of images are not fixed..... its increases dynamically.. can u give me any sample code how can i implement this

Comment: @Rox from looking at your previous posts you seem to be lurching from one piece of sample code to another. While its one way to learn a language, its not very nice on the rest of the community to be basically writing your app, one question at a time. Take some time to study and research more about UIKit and Cocoa Touch. You'll need to understand, UIScrollView, UIImageView and UITableViewCell contentViews, to make progress on your question. The info is out there but it will take a little time for it all to sink in. Best of luck.

Comment: I don't have sample code at hand that demonstrates what you're looking for. Sorry. The tutorial mentioned below by Omar is as good a place to start as any. But if that isn't making much since, I'd step back a bit from your app and look into getting some good books or watch iTunes U courses on UIKit and Obj-c development.

Comment: No problems. And keep engaging with the Stack Overflow community!

Answer (score 0):

Implement a table view with four images per row, tag each image according to the row. Add tap recognizer to each image, and based on the image tag execute the code you wanted. Following is the code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *cellidentifier=@"cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

   if(cell==nil)
   {
       cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
   }
   int x=0;

    //configure the cell 
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
       UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hh.jpg"];
       UIImageView *im=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
       im.frame=CGRectMake(0+x, 0, 60, 60);
       x=x+61;

       im.tag=(indexPath.row*10)+i;
       im.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
       UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
       [im addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
       [cell addSubview:im];
    }

   //cell.backgroundView=img;
   [[cell textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
   [[cell detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

return cell;
}

- (void) tapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
     NSLog(@"Clicked Button With Tag =%i",recognizer.view.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your data first. Maybe an array of arrays would be a good approach.

```
-(void)prepareData
{
    NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    int dataPerCell = 4;
    int remainingData = [allImagesData count] % dataPerCell;
    int pagesForData = [allImagesData count] / dataPerCell;

    NSMutableArray *arrayToAdd = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int j = 0; j<[allImagesData count]; j++)
    {
        [arrayToAdd addObject:[allImagesData objectAtIndex:j]];

        //Check if dividing the array is needed
        if ([allImagesData count] > dataPerCell)
        {
            if ([arrayToAdd count] == dataPerCell)
            {
                NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayToAdd];
                [arrayToAdd removeAllObjects];
                [finalArray addObject:finalArray];
            }
            else if([arrayToAdd count] == remainingData && [finalArray count] == pagesForData)
            {
                NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayToAdd];
                [arrayToAdd removeAllObjects];
                [finalArray addObject:finalArray];
            }
        }
        else if([allImagesData count] <= dataPerCell)
        {
            NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayToAdd];
            if ([finalArray count] == [allImagesData count])
            {
                [finalArray addObject:finalArray];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will give you an array (finalArray) of another array, each array has four data.

You can create a class subclass of `UITableViewCell`, and add property to it, like four `UIImageViews`, and put them to places. I assume in your case, place them horizontally.

```
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
      return [finalArray count];
 }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
    }

    //This will throw an exception if [allImagesData count] < 4 OR your [allImagesData count]  % 4 != 0
    [cell.imageVw1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectAtIndex:0]]];
    [cell.imageVw2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectAtIndex:1]]];
    [cell.imageVw3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectAtIndex:2]]];
    [cell.imageVw4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] objectAtIndex:3]]];

    return cell;
}
```

**NOTE:** the code is not tested.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create a custom cell subclass - see the tutorial *[Custom UITableViewCells with Interface Builder](http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder)* . Also, I would recommend to do some further study and research about [Cocoa Touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_Touch) framework. Good luck.